# NativeScript change Image Color - css filter property

Tags: css, nativescript

How can I change the **color** of my images in **NativeScript**, while it won't support *filter* property : *contrast*, *hue* , ...?

should I manually change my Images by a photo-editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS based image filters are not supported in {N}, try [nativescript-image-filters](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-image-filters) plugin.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-image-filters
```